# Expressão regular C# aplicação de console

Tags: c#, regex, console

Tenho uma lista de palavras, por exemplo:

```
São Paulo
9000-000 a 9999-9999
Barigui
8000-0000 a 8999-999
```

Quero pegar apenas os números, com o traço mesmo e separar, em outra lista por exemplo, sei que a expressão é essa `/[0-9-]/g`, no site [regexr.com](https://regexr.com) funciona, mas não parece funcionar no código:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[0-9-]/g]");
Match match = regex.Match("9000-001 a 9999-999");
if(match.Success) 
{
   Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Não acontece nada, não imprime nada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>*Apesar de eu não programar profissionalmente em C# (tenho uma **vaga** noção), vou falar um pouco sobre a regex em questão.*</sup>

---

O site que você citou ([regexr.com](https://regexr.com/)) usa a sintaxe `/expressão/flags`. Ou seja, no seu caso (`/[0-9-]/g`) a expressão é `[0-9-]` e o modificador/flag é `g`. Note que as barras são apenas delimitadores, indicando o início e fim da expressão regular. Já o `g` é o modificador "global", ou seja, serve para indicar que queremos pegar todas as ocorrências da string que satisfaçam a regex. Sem essa flag, apenas a primeira ocorrência é retornada: [veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/GimTQG/1) uma regex com a flag `g` setada, e note que ela pega todas ocorrências de números. Mas se tirarmos o `g`, [apenas a primeira ocorrência é retornada](https://regex101.com/r/G3Npe4/1).

O ponto é que nem o `/`, nem o `g` fazem parte da regex em si. Claro que algumas linguagens, como o JavaScript por exemplo, usam esta sintaxe para criar uma regex diretamente:

```js
// criar uma regex em JavaScript
let r = /[0-9-]/g;
```

Já em outras linguagens, como no Python, não é necessário colocar `/` e `g`:

```py
# criar regex em Python
import re
r = re.compile('[0-9-]')
```

E para pegar todas as ocorrências, não se usa a flag `g`, pois existem métodos específicos para isso, [como o `findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall).

Tudo isso é para dizer que cada linguagem implementa regex de uma maneira, e não necessariamente será preciso colocar `/` e `g` ao criar a expressão.

---

Pelo que vi na [documentação da classe `Regex`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.7.2), ela não precisa da `/`, pois o construtor recebe a regex diretamente. Ou seja, quando você fez `new Regex(@"[0-9-]/g]")`, criou uma expressão que corresponde a:

- `[0-9-]`: um dígito de 0 a 9 **ou** um hífen
- seguido do caractere `/`
- seguido do caractere `g`
- seguido do caractere `]`

Por isso ela não encontrou nenhum *match*, pois a string testada (`"9000-001 a 9999-999"`) até possui números e hífens, mas eles não estão seguidos de `/g]`. Esta regex só funcionaria se tivesse algo como `"9999-999/g]"`, [veja aqui um exemplo](https://ideone.com/3Gvi9m). Então a primeira coisa é **remover** `/g]` da expressão.

A seguir, vamos ver o que sobrou: `[0-9-]`. Esta expressão [corresponde a **um único caractere**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), que pode ser um dígito de 0 a 9 ou um hífen. Ou seja, se a string tiver apenas hífens, ela funcionará. [Veja aqui um exemplo](https://ideone.com/iE6s3y). E se ela tiver somente dígitos (sem nenhum hífen), também funcionará, [veja](https://ideone.com/J98THt).

---

O ideal é [ser mais específico sobre o que você quer obter da string](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#what_you_want). Se quer "dígitos, seguido de hífen, seguido de mais dígitos", faça uma regex que seja o mais próximo possível disso.

Primeiro, podemos usar o [atalho `\d`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html), que é um sinônimo para `[0-9]`. E também podemos usar [quantificadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) para especificar quantos dígitos serão considerados. Exemplos:

- `\d{4}`: exatamente 4 dígitos
- `\d{2,4}`: entre 2 e 4 dígitos
- `\d{3,}`: no mínimo 3 dígitos (e sem limite máximo)
- `\d+`: um ou mais dígitos (equivalente a `\d{1,}`)

Escolha o que melhor se encaixar nos seus casos. Baseado nos seus exemplos, vou considerar que antes do hífen são 4 dígitos, e depois do hífen são 3 ou 4 dígitos (mas mude conforme os seus casos de uso). Então a expressão fica assim:

```
\d{4}-\d{3,4}
```

Com isso, se a string só tiver hífens, por exemplo, a regex não pega. Ela só vai considerar números, seguidos de hífen, seguidos de números. Mas ainda há um porém.

Se a string for `"1111-2222-3333"`, a regex pegará o trecho `1111-2222`, [veja aqui](https://ideone.com/CF1XbK).
Ou se a string tiver mais dígitos que o desejado, como `"123456-12345"`, ainda sim a regex pegará o trecho `3456-1234`, [veja aqui](https://ideone.com/vZrtcZ).

Para limitar que antes dos primeiros dígitos, e depois dos últimos, não há outros dígitos adicionais, podemos usar `\b`, que significa ["word boundary"](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#wordboundary) (algo como "fronteira de palavra"), para garantir que antes e depois da expressão não há dígitos ou qualquer outro caractere alfa-numérico:

```
\b\d{4}-\d{3,4}\b
```

Com isso, a regex não pega mais casos como `"123456-12345"`, [veja aqui](https://ideone.com/pS2Z3a).

---

Só mais um detalhe: pelo que vi na [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.7.2), o método [`Match`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=netframework-4.7.2) só retorna a primeira ocorrência da regex na string. Mas como você quer pegar todas as ocorrências, pode usar [`Matches`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=netframework-4.7.2). Adaptando o exemplo da documentação, o código ficaria assim:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b\d{4}-\d{3,4}\b");
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches("9000-001 a 9999-999")) {
   Console.WriteLine("Encontrei '{0}' na posição {1}", match.Value, match.Index);
}
```

A saída é:

> Encontrei '9000-001' na posição 0
>   Encontrei '9999-999' na posição 11

[Veja aqui](https://ideone.com/O1h0ug) este exemplo no Ideone.

Answer (score 4):

Também disponível no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/GrH0ZF).

Tente assim:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Regex r = new Regex(@"[\d-]+");
        var matches = r.Matches("9000-001 a 9999-999");

        foreach (var match in matches.Cast<Match>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Encontrada a seguinte ocorrência: '{match.Value}'");
        }
    }
}
```

onde, na expressão regular:

- `\d` é o curinga para dígitos
- `+` é o quantificador para uma ou mais ocorrências

Veja que ocorrências do tipo `999-` ou `-12409-` também serão obtidas com a expressão regular fornecida. Para contornar isso e manter o formato de ocorrência mostrado, use a expressão regular `\d+-\d+`.

Comment: Tem outro porém com `[\d-]+`, que é aceitar strings como `"------"`, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/G3Npe4/2). `\d+-\d+` é mais garantido mesmo..